# how to deal with Segmentation fault in dynamically allocated struct C

Tags: c, file, struct, segmentation-fault

I have written a program that reads in words from a text file. There is one word per line. I need to find how many times each word repeats. To find this out so far i have read the words in from the file and placed them all in a dynamically allocated array of struct. My problem is that the program keeps segmentation faulting whenever i try to run it. I assume there is a problem with how i am dynamically allocating the data. 
Code is as follows;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

//struct
struct _data {
    char *word;
    int number;
};


//scan for size of file
int SCAN(FILE *data) {
    int size = 0;
    char  s_temp[50];
    while (1) {
        fscanf(data, "%s", s_temp);
        if (feof(data)) break;
        size++;
   }
   return size;
}
//load content into struct
int LOAD(FILE *data, int size, struct _data *Wordstruct){
    int i;
    char temp[50];
    for (i=0; i <size; i++){
        fscanf(data, "%s", temp , &Wordstruct[i].word, &Wordstruct[i].number);
        Wordstruct[i].word =calloc(strlen(temp), sizeof(char));
        strcpy(Wordstruct[i].word, temp);
        if(strcasecmp(Wordstruct[i].word, temp) ==0){
            Wordstruct[i].number++;
        }

    }
    return size;
}
//count how many times each word repeats
void COUNT(struct _data *Wordstruct, int size){
    int i;
    int count;
    count =0;
    char *word;
    if (strcasecmp(Wordstruct[i].word, word)==0){
            count++;
            for(i=0; i<size; i++){
            printf("%s\n",Wordstruct[i].word,"occurs:\t",count);
            }
        }
    }
//main routine
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int size;
    FILE *data;
    struct _data *Wordlist;
        if(argc <2){
            printf("Not enough arguments\n");
        }
        else{
            FILE *data= fopen(argv[1],"r");
            size =SCAN(data);
            LOAD(data, size, Wordlist);
            COUNT(Wordlist, size);
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) `Wordlist` is not allocated. 2) `calloc(strlen(temp), sizeof(char));` allocate size need `strlen(temp)+1` 3) `strcasecmp(Wordstruct[i].word, word)` :  `word` is not initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't allocated memory for `Wordlist`. Add

```
Wordlist = malloc(size*sizeof(*Wordlist));
```

before the call to `LOAD`.

And, as pointed out by @BLUEPIXY in comments, change

```
Wordstruct[i].word =calloc(strlen(temp), sizeof(char));
```

to

```
Wordstruct[i].word =calloc(strlen(temp)+1, sizeof(char));
```

Answer (score 0):

***Change*** this:

```
Wordstruct[i].word =calloc(strlen(temp), sizeof(char));
```

***To*** this:

```
Wordstruct[i].word =calloc(strlen(temp)+1, sizeof(char));
```

You need to account for NULL terminator, `strlen()` does not do that for you here.